# Create column in R dataframe based on name of the column to make a time series

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-science

I have a data frame in R which has two columns as shown below. It has one column of tower creation date in a city. The data represents on which day, a tower was installed in a city. e.g. on 1st April, in these few cities, tower was installed and so, this data goes until 2020.

```
df_example <- read_table2("c_date   city_name
4/1/2016    Mbombela
4/1/2016    Ethekwini
4/1/2016    Ekurhuleni
4/1/2016    Prince Albert
4/1/2016    Ethekwini
4/1/2016    of Johannesburg
5/1/2016    Prince Albert
5/1/2016    Ethekwini
5/1/2016    of Johannesburg")
```

Now, I want to create a dataframe based on this above dataframe, where we have a unique column for each **City** which tells the number of times, this has appeared consecutively in timeseries, giving an increase in count that, by the time, how many towers were places in each cities from 2016 to 2020, so it becomes time series data for each city.

Desired_output

```
#>   c_date   Mbombela Ethekwini Ekurhuleni Prince    of
#>   <chr>       <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 4/1/2016        1         2          1      1     1
#> 2 5/1/2016        1         3          1      2     2
```

Comment: Can you please explain the desired output in a bit detail?  it isn't clear

Comment: The dates in all 6 rows are same so how come different values for any city?

Comment: Basically, the data is, on which date, where a tower was placed in cities, so I want to create a time series object for each city, with date and each city column getting increased counts as they were placed in that particular city, I am updating the output.

Comment: @AnilGoyal I updated, hope it make sense now, please let me know.

Comment: I'm sorry, i am unable to understand

Comment: @AnilGoyal I added more information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my take on this problem

```r
library(tidyverse)

df_example <- read_table2("c_date   city_name
4/1/2016    Mbombela
4/1/2016    Ethekwini
4/1/2016    Ekurhuleni
4/1/2016    Prince Albert
4/1/2016    Ethekwini
4/1/2016    of Johannesburg
5/1/2016    Prince Albert
5/1/2016    Ethekwini
5/1/2016    of Johannesburg")
#> Warning: 4 parsing failures.
#> row col  expected    actual         file
#>   4  -- 2 columns 3 columns literal data
#>   6  -- 2 columns 3 columns literal data
#>   7  -- 2 columns 3 columns literal data
#>   9  -- 2 columns 3 columns literal data


df_example %>% 
  mutate(value = 1) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = city_name,values_fn = sum,values_fill = 0) %>% 
  mutate(across(.cols = -c_date,.fns = cumsum))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 6
#>   c_date   Mbombela Ethekwini Ekurhuleni Prince    of
#>   <chr>       <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 4/1/2016        1         2          1      1     1
#> 2 5/1/2016        1         3          1      2     2
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: this is the error, I got.. 
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
x cumsum not defined for "Date" objects

Comment: Your date is also probably a double... let me fix that, just change the where(is.double) to -Date

Answer (score 1):

Do you want this (I'm not sure due to insufficient data/details)

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  group_by(c_date, city_name) %>%
  summarise(val = n()) %>%
  pivot_wider(
  id_cols = c_date,
  names_from = city_name,
  values_from = val,
  values_fill = 0
)
```

Comment: I got an error - "Error: Can't convert <double> to <list>."

Comment: Try it now, mutate changed to summarise

Answer (score 1):

Use packages `tidyr` and `dplyr`. Assuming your data.frame is named `df`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dates <- df %>% distinct(c_date)
df %>% group_by(city_name, c_date) %>%
  summarise(buildings=n()) %>%
  inner_join(dates, by=c('c_date')) %>%
  group_by(city_name) %>%
  arrange(c_date) %>%
  mutate(buildings=cumsum(buildings, na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from=city_name, values_from=buildings, values_fill=0)
```

Comment: I was able to create a matrix from your example, but in between it have zeroes, which has to be last value, if on that date, no value was added.